# Why does the XHR succeed and show in chromeDevTools but is undefined and cant be parsed by JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

here's the script:

```
  function getReq(){
 $.post('../include/getLoggedUser.php', {
  //nothing to transmit
}).then((loggedUser) => {
    $.post("../include/getRequests.php", {
    ID:loggedUser
  })
}).then((data) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log("data for table is", data)
  $("#requestTable").html(data);
})
}
```

What is returned from "getRequests.php" is markup in JSON. 
Just for Reference, I'll post the backend code so you can look up what is put into the response. "$result" is what is returned at the end of the php.

```html
<?php
/*
================================================================================
Wennn diese Datei aufgerufen wird und der Wert "ID" als Int übergeben wurde wird
eine Tabelle, die alle Anfragen anzeigt, zurückgegeben.
================================================================================
*/
  if(isset($_POST["ID"])){
    try{
      $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=arbeitsplatzverwaltung',
      'verwalter','N7pY1OTl2gaBbc51');
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    session_start();
    
    $userRole = $connection->query("
      SELECT name
      FROM rolle
      WHERE id = (
        SELECT rolle
        FROM benutzer_rollen
        WHERE benutzer='".$_POST["ID"]."'
      )
    ")->fetchAll()[0][0];
    if($userRole == "admin"){

      
      $result .= "<thead><tr><td>Von</td><td>Bis</td><td>Benutzer</td><td>Raum/Platz
      </td><td>Aktionen</td></tr></thead><tbody>";

      $allReservation = $connection->query("
        SELECT id, anfang, ende, benutzer, arbeitsplatz
        FROM reservierung
        WHERE status='angefragt'
      ")->fetchAll();
      foreach($allReservation as $row){
        $user = $connection->query("
          SELECT name, vorname
          FROM benutzer
          WHERE id='".$row["benutzer"]."'
        ")->fetchAll()[0];
        $position = $connection->query("
          SELECT raum, nummer
          FROM arbeitsplatz
          WHERE ID = '".$row["arbeitsplatz"]."'
        ")->fetchAll()[0];
        $raumbild = $connection->query("
          SELECT bild
          FROM raum
          WHERE name ='".$position["raum"]."'
        ")->fetchAll()[0][0];


        $result .= "<tr><td>".date("d.m.y",strtotime($row["anfang"]))."</td><td>"
        .date("d.m.y",strtotime($row["ende"]))."</td><td>".$user["name"]." "
        .$user["vorname"]."</td><td><a>".$position["raum"]."/"
        .$position["nummer"]."<div><img class=\"hoverImage\"src=\"".$raumbild.
        "\" /></div></a></td><td><div class=\"form-inline form-horizontal\">
        <select id=\"statusDrop".$row["id"]."\" class=\"form-control\">
        <option>genehmigen</option><option>ablehnen</option></select>
        <button class='btn btn-default' onclick=\"submitStatus(".$row["id"].
        ");\">Ok</button></div></td></tr>";
      }
      $result .= "</tbody></table>";
      echo json_encode($result);
    }
  }


?>
```

In the chromeDevTools, the response is displayed correctly as HTML elements ("" and the like). However, when I try to output the results via console.log I get "undefined". When I try to parse it with "JSON.parse()" it gives me a syntax error saying that there was an "unexepected expression at line 1 column 1" of the data.

I don't understand this, especially since I used the very same script code before in other parts of the site. There, this problem never appeared.

Comment: Why encoding in JSON something that is just a string and not an object/array?

Comment: It's because you're not returning valid JSON. First `console.log(data)` in your `then` handler to see exactly what you are returning. It seems like you can just return the HTML and be done.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already tried logging just the string without parsing, but then it says undefined. Also, when the markup is injected into the respective element (see last bit of code), no table appears.

Comment: I also tried echoing without "json_encode", plus removing the JSON.parse() on the script. Didn't really change much, although in the devtools a few more results show up so "json_encode" wasn't the best idea here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get undefined for `data` in the `.then((data) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data)` block because this "then" is attached to the call to getLoggedUser, not getRequests. So it receives a different response (and also probably executes before getRequests has completed).

So you need to do two things

1) Attach your callback to the correct AJAX call

2) stop trying to use JSON to try and wrap around HTML. What you're passing to json_encode() isn't JSON, and there's no need for it to be - just return the HTML as a string and append it directly to your HTML.

**JS:**

```
function getReq(){
  $.post('../include/getLoggedUser.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then((loggedUser) => {
    $.post("../include/getRequests.php", {
      ID:loggedUser
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log("data for table is", data)
        $("#requestTable").html(data);
    })
  })
}
```

**PHP:**

Simply replace

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

with

```
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :=)